# Create multidimensional matrices from two multidimensional cells

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, size, cell

I have a cell `f{k}` with `k` matrices inside it, where `k=1:96`. For each `k`, the matrices have different lengths. For example `length(f{1})==13` and `length(f{96})==80`. In addition, I have another cell `W{k}` with `k=1:96`. Again, for each `k`, the matrices have different lengths. For example `length(W{1})==49` and `length(W{96})==65`.

Following is the output for cell f, for the first 9 elements of cell `f`:

Columns 1 through 9

```
  [13×1 double]    [24×1 double]    [36×1 double]    [43×1 double]    [48×1 double]    [65×1 double]    [81×1 double]    [95×1 double]    [107×1 double]
```

Similarly, following is the output for cell `W`, representing first 9 elements of `W`:

Columns 1 through 9

```
  [1×49 double]    [1×49 double]    [1×49 double]    [1×48 double]    [1×47 double]    [1×49 double]    [1×49 double]    [1×48 double]    [1×47 double]
```

Now, for each `k=1:96`, I want to create a matrix (say `M`) which should contain indices of `W` and `f`. For example, if I want `M(1)`, I should get matrix with size `f{1}*W{1}`. Note that `f{1}` and `W{1}` have different lengths and new matrices will be formed of different lengths, for each `k`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You meant `M{1}` instead of `M(1)`, right?

Comment: When you say `f{1}*W{1}` (which are `13x1` * `1x49`) you expect to get the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product), right?

Comment: Btw you don't seem to really have *multidimensional* cells.

Comment: @SardarUsama Yes M{1} also works. I can then maybe convert this M{1} to a matrix. Also I am quite new to programming(MATLAB) in general. Sorry for the wrong syntax

Comment: @Dev-iL Not a product but I wanted to show the size of that matrix

Comment: So you intend to convert all of the cells inside M into separate matrices? Please *don't do that*. And is your only concern size and you're actually  not interested in multiplying them?

Comment: I intend to convert it into matrices as I need these matrices as input  for an optimization problem

Comment: So access them as `M{1}` , `M{2}` etc. Don't convert them into separate 96 matrices. That's a very bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this can be done using `cellfun`. Here's a demonstration:

```
c1 = {[1;1;1],[1;1;1;1;1],[1;1]}; % {3×1} {5×1} {2×1}
c2 = {[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]}; % {1×2} {1×3} {1×5}
out = cellfun(@times,c1,c2,'UniformOutput',false);
```

```
out =

  1×3 cell array

    {3×2 double}    {5×3 double}    {2×5 double}
```

If you only want the **sizes** you can do something like that:

```
M = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x,y)[size(x,1) size(y,2)],c1,c2,'UniformOutput',false).');
```

```
M =

     3     2
     5     3
     2     5
```

Comment: `{ }` should be `[ ]` in the result. No? Your code is correct though

Comment: This multiplies the two cells, Which is not intended. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @Kulkarni - you can take the output and apply `size` to each element..... @SardarUsama - I copy-pasted the output from my R2017....

Comment: You said: " So access them as M{1} , M{2} etc. Don't convert them into separate 96 matrices. That's a very bad idea". I had exactly this in mind. To make 96 matrices of different sizes and then use the indices from each of these 96 matrices as input for the optimization problem

Comment: @Dev-iL Just verified (in R2017a). It should be `[ ]`

Comment: okay I will try and explain what I need. I have a cell f with size (1 by 96). Now, for each of these 96 indices, there exists a matrix of different length.  For eg. size (f{1})= (13 by 1). Similiarly for W{1:96}, the matrix sizes differ. For eg size (W{1})=(1 BY 49) So I want to creatE 96 matrices of different sizes, which are extracted from cells f and W. Thus 1st matrix would be of size (13 by 49). Is it a bit clear? @SardarUsama

Comment: @Dev-iL. Any thoughts on the above explanation? I am really in the need of this.

Comment: Dear @Dev-iL, the solution you suggested as out = cellfun(@times,c1,c2,'UniformOutput',false);   works really nice. However, it is multiplying the elements from c1,c2 (or f and W, in my case). Is there a way in which I can extract the values corresponding to the elements from c1,c2 from a different matrix (say X) and then display the values of elements inside the new cell "out", instead of multiplying them?

Comment: @S.Kulkarni Sounds like you might need to make a `meshgrid`. Instead of explaining what you want in in the comments, this should be a part of your question. Better yet, open a new question and explain exactly what you need **including** a [mcve]. Please add an example with some small `f`, `W`, `X` matrices and show us **exactly** what the output should be. You can link to this question if it helps provide context. You should always provide a demonstration because without it questions like this one (at its current state) risk getting closed with a reason of "_unclear what you're asking_".